# Apache not serve page from specific ip of server

Tags: apache, virtualhost

My server has 2 interfaces:

```
eth0 - 192.168.1.1
eth0:0 - 192.168.0.1

telnet 192.168.1.1 80
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.blah.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
// All data OK
```

But,

```
telnet 192.168.0.1 80
Trying 192.168.0.1...
Connected to 192.168.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.blah.com

HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

What's wrong?

---

after make many tests, I observe the following scenario:

**web server:**

eth0 - 192.168.1.1
eth0:0 - 192.168.0.1

**client:**

eth0 - 192.168.1.10
eth0:0 - 192.168.0.10

**in client:**

telnet 192.168.1.1 80
//all ok

telnet 192.168.0.1 80
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

BUT,

**in server:**

ping 192.168.0.10
//ok

**and in client again:**

telnet 192.168.0.1 80
// MIRACLE. Works!

I don't know why the connection only work if the webserver first ping the alias interface of client. 
Obs1: all works fine if I test (telnet) locally from server. I think that apache settings is ok

Obs2: This linux machine (server), is a VM Box, running inside MS Hyper-V. The network interface (eth0) is connected as bridge. Im going crazy with this.

Comment: There's not enough information here for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your VirtualHost directive probably specifies an interface or hostname instead of *

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the problem. Another client was using same ip from web server. When arp table has ip of client not worked, when has server ip work.

Sorry for my mistake